# Beginner issue with <div>

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website with the title in a div box at the top of the page. The issue is that when i put a heading in the box it doesn't stay in the box

```
<div style="width:1000px;height:40px;background:grey;border:3px solid;border-radius:10px;opacity:0.85;overflow:hidden;">
<h1 style="text-align:center;">
 Welcome To A Website
 </h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't stay inside the box"? Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ya2Qg/.

Comment: It appears that the `<h1>` is taller than the `<div>`. Since you've set `overflow:hidden`, the `<div>` hides the overflowing content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a HTML file, each browser interpret the elements on its way. For example: some browsers have an extra margin config at an `<p>` or some different line-height property. Because of that, normally, the developers use a **Reset CSS** (example: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). It reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on.

In your case, `h1` by default have some configs that make it go out of the `div` box (margin and padding, as I checked). You can solve it using: margin: 0; padding: 0; at `<h1>` element. My suggestion for future projects: use a Reset CSS and you'll have more control in things like that.

Another suggestion: use a CSS file to organize your own styles. Inline styling isn't a good thing when you've a common thing to modify and have to go file by file to do that. With CSS you only change the file and it reflects at all HTML that uses it.

Well, my CSS fix suggestion is:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h1>Welcome to a Website </h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    /* Make title go to entire screen*/
    width: 100%;
    display: block;

    /* You visual config */
    height:40px;
    background:grey;
    border:3px solid;
    border-radius:10px;
    opacity:0.85;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:40px;
}

div h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I used width:100%;display:block instead of width:1000px because I assumed that you want a block that occupies 100% width from screen. Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/brunoluiz/NyLAD/

Well, good luck with HTML and CSS studies!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the margin of your `h1` to `0`, also note that you should place the styles in some CSS file or right inside the page (between the `<style>` tags):

```
div {
  width:1000px;
  height:40px;
  background:grey;
  border:3px solid;
  border-radius:10px;
  opacity:0.85;
  overflow:hidden;
  line-height:40px;
}
div h1 {
  margin:0;
}
```

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/6NDNB/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you specified a specific height for the box in the style. Try removing the "height:40px;" part.
Now the div style looks like this:

```
style="width:1000px;background:grey;border:3px solid;border-radius:10px;opacity:0.85;overflow:hidden;"
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8Xk5/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the height of the size of the header is too big for the height you set on your div. Try taking out the height from the div's style, like so:

```
<div style="width:1000px;background:grey;border:3px solid;border-radius:10px;opacity:0.85;overflow:hidden;">
<h1 style="text-align:center;">
 Welcome To A Website
</h1>
</div>
```